# how to get how much eth adress put into crowdsale contract?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, crowdsale

I want to write function to get how much eth address put into smart contract, how do I do that? im making erc20 token.

edit: I meant that I want to get how much specific investor invested eth, because token price will be increasing with time (so I can't just convert tokens back to eth) , and if some conditions will be not met I want to refund all funds that was invested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is "How can I keep track of how much each account contributed?" then you just need a `mapping`:

```
mapping (address => uint256) public howMuch;
function deposit() public payable {
    howMuch[msg.sender] += msg.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The global `msg.value` is the amount of wei the address sent with the transaction.

Comment: yeah, but if address made several transactions?.